# How can I shade an area under a curve between two lines in matplotlib / pandas?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to recreate this chart, more or less, using matplotlib:

[image]

Except in mine the center is 100 and the standard deviation is 16 (like IQ). This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats as stats
x = np.linspace(50,150,100)
iq = stats.norm.pdf(x, 100, 16)
plt.plot(x,iq)
```

That generates a normal curve like this:

[image]

So far so good. But I'm at a loss for how to shade areas under the curve.

Comment: you can use `fill_between`. Check [this link for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235668/how-do-i-color-the-area-below-the-two-curves)

Comment: If you want the arrows/text as well, I'd suggest looking at the [annotate](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `plt.fill_between`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

plt.style.use('ggplot')

mean = 100
std = 16

x = np.linspace(mean - 5 * std, mean + 5 * std, 1000)

iq = stats.norm(mean, std)

plt.plot(x, iq.pdf(x), 'r-', lw=3)

colors = ['c', 'r', 'b', 'g', ]
colors = colors + list(reversed(colors))

for i, color in zip(range(-4, 4), colors):
    low = mean + i * std
    high = mean + (i + 1) * std
    px = x[np.logical_and(x >= low, x <= high)]
    plt.fill_between(
        px,
        iq.pdf(px),
        color=color,
        alpha=0.5,
        linewidth=0,
    )

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=300)
```

[image: result]